# working with Evolution Mail and web calendar using RRULE fail because of X-EVOLUTION-ENDDATE in rrule

Tags: evolution

I am wondering if someone can help me shed some light on a X-EVOLUTION-ENDDATE property in a rrule that from what I can see was generated by Evolution Mail for an event.

I'm new to Evolution Mail, coming from thunderbird, but kinda like Evo Mail now.  Anyway, I also have a web app that loads my calendar that worked fine with TB.  But since I've used Evo Mail my web app calendar crashed because rrule complained about a bad property in a rrule string starting with
"RRULE;X-EVOLUTION-ENDDATE=20241223T140000Z:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=51;BYDAY=MO;"

I'm assuming this is Evo Mail.  When looking online I found someone mention "The X-EVOLUTION-ENDDATE, which you refer to, is known only to the evolution-data-server"

Does anyone know anything about this property and why rrule.js does not like it?  I tried creating a recurring event with Evo Mail and this time the rule is not present so I couldn't recreate the issue, but I can only assume it will return.

Thanks for reading